# LaTex-Code does not compile apa7 reference list

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, lists, apa7

My goal is to compile just the reference list based on BibTex citations from Google scholar. The format should be apa7 an I used following code

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\title{Z}
\author{X}
\date{Y}

\begin{document}

\maketitle   
\cite{agras2015investigating}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

my bibliographic information are stored in "mybib.bib" looking like this

```
@article{agras2015investigating,
  title={Investigating the predictive abilities of Schwartz’s ten universal values on five work performance outcome behaviors},
  author={Agras, S{\"u}leyman and Ates, Husameddin},
  journal={Social and Basic Sciences Research Review},
  volume={3},
  number={1},
  pages={16--31},
  year={2015}
}
```

I used the manual from this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/apa7?lang=de

And for each individual citation I get this warning: Citation 'agras2015investigating' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.

and I don't know why it doesn't relate to my bib.bib and identifies the \cite-citation as a citation.

This is what my pdf looks like at this point: [image: example picture]

Every help is appreciated, thanks!!

Here you can see my overleaf-surface[image: overleaf-surface] and the content of the mybib.bib file[image: mybib.bib]

I checked the same code in another project where it works. Is it possible that it has something to do with the Bibtex references? But as I said, I used the same procedure in another project and as soon as I copy the content from this mybib.bib elsewhere, the same error occurs.

Comment: overleaf? that should have run biber for you, check your biber log file (.blg) available in overleaf's other files menu

Comment: Is the `mybib.bib` in the same directory as the `.tex` file? I ran your code with my TeXworks local installation (using `\begin{filecontents}`), Overleaf  (using `\begin{filecontents}`) and Overleaf with `mybib.bib` in the same directory and all 3 worked correctly. Have you followed the Overleaf instructions for `.bib` files [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_bibliographies_on_Overleaf)? If you have, can you share a screenshot of your directory on Overleaf (on the left)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but still nothing works with this particular reference list... I added two more screenshots. As I said, this problem doesn't occur in other reference list using the same procedure.

Comment: I think you need to contact Overleaf support as I have a feeling this a glitch/bug that has affected your project. If it works in other projects, works on my Overleaf account and works on my local latex then it must be a bug on their side. If you go to menu (top left), click it and go to the bottom it says "contact us", click on it. Put in the subject "Bib not being detected" or something, don't change the project URL and then describe the issue and put a link to this question (the url of this question is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/674820) and ask for help, all I can advise, sorry

Comment: Thank you for your effort!!